# Added NSWindow as child of another window, but not persisting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My goal is to position an NSWindow relative to another NSWindow, such that when the parent is dragged around, the child moves along with it.

When I poke around with the debugger, I can see the NSWindow parenting relationship getting established correctly. However, in a later part of my code, that same NSWindow returns nil when I try to fetch the parent. I figured only an explicit call to removeChildWindow would eliminate the parenting, unless there's something else going on here like I'm setting up the parenting incorrectly. Are there other ways for an NSWindow to lose its parent/child relationship?

```
someFunction(NSWindow* parentWindow) {
    NSWindow* wnd = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                    styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                    defer:NO];
    [parentWindow addChildWindow:wnd ordered:NSWindowAbove];
}
```

later:

```
anotherFunction(NSWindow* window) {
  NSWindow* parentWindow = [window parentWindow]; // debugger shows nil
}
```

Comment: nope, it's the same window as wnd earlier

Comment: You need to provide more info. Does parentHandle, or some other object, retain parentWindow?  Are both windows visible at the point you describe as "later" (the parent window is shown as nil by the debugger)?

Comment: I removed some of the irrelevant bits, yes, I keep a list in the class of the NSView content views for each window (so not directly retaining the parentWindow but do I need to...?)

Both windows are indeed visible, both on the screen and when I use debug view hierarchy in xcode.

Comment: Are either of the windows ordered out between when the parent-child relationship is established and when it seems to have been broken?

Comment: there's a few calls to orderFront for the child window but my presumption would be that shouldn't affect the parenting relationship.

Comment: I have found the possible problem. I have a call to set the child window visibility to false. When I do this and invoke its parentWindow method again, that returns nil. Is that legit? Is that a bug? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: @damonkashu, did you find solution for this? Even I have similar problem, I have added a NSViewController as popup in a NSWindow, and I have requirement to hide and show the popup. but if I hide the popup once, and again show, it doesn't move with parent Window, its stays whereever it was initially positioned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had a call to change the window visibility to false:

```
[wnd setIsVisible:false];
```

And when I tried reading its parent again, that ends up being nil. Who would have guessed it, this doesn't appear to be documented.

Comment: `-[NSWindow setIsVisible:]` is an odd method. It's not actually a core part of `NSWindow`. It's part of a category on `NSWindow` for scripting support (see NSWindowScripting.h). It's basically a wrapper around ordering the window out. There's no other "visibility" notion for windows. Anyway, the behavior is documented. See the [10.7 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#X10_7Notes) under "NSWindow - Child Windows Ordering Out".